# Defining Android Fragment in xml

Tags: android

I've never defined a fragment in an activity's layout before, I usually do it grammatically. Although I can see the benefits of doing this for simple fragments that do not need to be swapped, removed etc. So I was wondering if I define a fragment in an activity's xml layout. Will that fragment also require it's own java class? How would I access the fragment in the activity's code? I only know how to do that for views.

Sorry if this is a mundane question, but the developer site wasn't quite clear.

thanks!

Comment: you can put fragment in view using `fragment` tag and can access it in your activity using method `findFragmentById()`

Comment: You should really have gone through google search a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

Type this in layout:(main_activity)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<fragment android:name="com.mamutek.android.protectorx.MainFragment"
          android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
}
```

Fragment:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);

    Button startButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.start);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}
}
```

To get events in Activity class Implement listener with interface

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html